# Query Apple's Servers for Update Using Script?

Tags: ios, software-update, script

Is it possible to have a script or some sort of command-line tool that will query Apple's update servers to see what the latest version of an OS is? For example, I'd like to alert somewhere when a new iOS version is released without me having to check tech news websites or directly on my iPhone, that all seems too reactive.

Perhaps something like this already exists? Perhaps I just need to better understand how devices talk to Apple to know if they have an update available to them?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What would you use to script this? Apple publishes web pages on all updates, so I could see you scraping those pages or watching a Twitter feed that already scrapes the pages.

Comment: I was thinking it might be possible to send a request to one of the update servers. Is there a Twitter account that already does this?

Comment: Yes. I like https://istheapplestoredown.com/ios

Comment: @bmike Ah, nice, that one even has an API which returns JSON objects :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has pages up beneath https://support.apple.com/en_US/downloads/ios for each major iOS release. Looking at [About iOS 13 Updates](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210393) one can see an overview of all available iOS13 versions.

[image]

In the HTML source this is coded as

```
<p><a href="#1341"><img alt="" src="/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/il/spacer.png" width="76">iOS 13.4.1<br>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
<p><a href="#135"><img alt="" src="/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/il/spacer.png" width="76">iOS 13.5<br>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
<p><a href="#1351"><img alt="" src="/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/il/spacer.png" width="76">iOS 13.5.1<br>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
```

So if you are willing to adapt your script with each major release of iOS/iPadOS you could use

```
curl -s "https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210393" | \
    sed -n '/\/library\/content/s|.*width="76">\([^<]*\)<.*|\1|p' | \
    tail -1
```

to get the most recent version available (`iOS 13.5.1` right now).

- `sed -n` runs sed suppressing any printing output unless specifically told so
- `/\/library\/content/` applies the following command to all lines matching `/library/content`
- `s|STRING-TO-MATCH|REPLACEMENT|` does pattern-based string replacement
- `.*width="76">\([^<]*\)<.*` takes the whole line and puts the part between `width="76">` and the following `<` into `\1`
- `\1` just replaces the whole line with the content of `\1` (which in this case is the version number)
- `p` prints the result to stdout

This obviously matches (and prints) every line (just leave out the `tail` to check) so at the end we just take the last line.

What changes for sure with each major release is the URL, what *might* change is the code to find and extract the relevant content from the page. The `sed/tail` combination above works for iOS12 and iOS13 at least.

<sub>PS: You could avoid `tail` by running</sub>

```
curl -s https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210393 | \
    sed -n '/\/library\/content/{s|.*width="76">\([^<]*\)<.*|\1|;h;}; ${g;p;}'
```

<sub>but this makes it hard to read for most people :-)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @nohillside ! This could very well get me what I need. Would you mind taking a moment to break down the expression used in the `sed` command? Not only do I want to make sure I can support this in the future on my own, but I'm curious how you were able to figure this out.

Comment: @bmkaiser see edit